# Why do medium format (digital) cameras capture better dynamic range?

Tags: dynamic-range, medium-format

Why do medium format (digital) cameras capture better dynamic range than smaller sensor cameras?

Comment: It's a duplicate but I think the accepted answer on the linked question is wrong, simply put a bigger sensor collects more light, therefore more photos, which is akin to taking a political poll, the more people you ask the more accurate it is, more accurate = less noise = greater dynamic range.

Comment: Sensor design can also play a big part.

Comment: popular myth: bigger sensor collects more light... yes, if you take it out from the camera and put under the sun. inside camera it can only collect the amount of light passed through the lens aperture. the physical aperture size of the medium and large format lens is usually comparable to the regular full frame lenses (or even smaller).